# How to add facial recognition based login in Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I have written a code (in python) to detect my face. Now I want to add this feature for login in my Ubuntu system. I searched over the internet but cannot find suitable answers.

I want to display an option/icon to select facial recognition and on clicking that, my facial recognition code starts running in the background. How can I achieve it? Please explain exactly where I need to make changes in an Ubuntu system for enabling and using such an option?

Comment: I believe you should write you program to work with PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules). Here are some links for start: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam, https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam, https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-pam.conf/

Comment: thanks @nobody. I will look into it and get back if any doubt comes.

Comment: Try this ... you may find what you are looking for... i am planning to build one for myself. https://github.com/mk-hasan/facekey/tree/master/facekey

Comment: @M.kHasan, thanks for your answer. I am looking for some explanation for registering my python program with OS. This python code for face detection should be activated when login screen appears.